# Search box moves cursor to end when expanding

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I found a bug in the search box. When the search box expands, the cursor moves to the end of the text field. If you're editing an already existing search text, this can cause what you are typing to end up in two places.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click in the search box and type `"test phrase"` including the quotes.
2. Click outside the search box so it shrinks again.
3. Double click on the word `phrase` in the search box so that only that word is selected. The closing quote should not be selected.
4. Type `paragraph`

Expected result: The cursor position should not move when the text field expands. Only the word `phrase` should be replaced with `paragraph` resulting in `"test paragraph"` in the text field.

Actual result: As soon as I start typing `paragraph` the text field expands and the cursor moves to the end of the text field. This results in the text field now showing `"test pa"ragraph`.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.25 on Windows 7.

UPDATE: I just tried this in Internet Explorer 8 and cannot reproduce the problem. This bug might be in Firefox. I'd appreciate knowing if other people can reproduce the bug in other web browsers.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 16 (Linux)

Comment: Can't repro on Firefox 9 either.

Comment: No problem in Firefox 8 and 9 on a Mac. (Nor in Chrome and Safari.)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 3.6 is quite old. For any given web browser, we only support the current (latest) major version, the previous major version, and depending on age, possibly the major version before that.

For example this means we support IE 9, IE 8, and (just barely, with no guarantees of things looking exactly right) IE7.

Is there any particular reason you're using such an old web browser?

Comment: I'm using it because it's still supported by the developer and it meets my requirements. I've looked at the changelogs of the new versions and they don't offer anything that I want or need beyond what I already have. Any upgrade of hardware or software incurs a cost, so I don't upgrade either unnecessarily.